# Clojure: unit-tests defined with with-test are not actually run

Tags: unit-testing, clojure

Example adapted from the standard documentation for `with-test`:

```
(ns my-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]))

(with-test
  (defn my-function [x y]
;;    (assert false)
    (+ x y))
  (is (= 4 (my-function 2 2)))
  (is (= 7 (my-function 3 4))))

(test #'my-function)
```

The 'with-test' block and the 'test' blocks are evaluated correctly (using C-x C-e in emacs/cider).
But then if I uncomment the 'assert' line they still are!
Directly evaluating (my-function 2 2) fails.

Comment: I am not able to replicate this issue.  Either using a REPL directly, or via a stock emacs/cider.  Try copy-pasting this code into the nrepl buffer and see if that works.  Make sure the nrepl is in the appropriate ns with clojure.test loaded.

Comment: @dorab it's probably a problem with my emacs setup. The (with-test ...) is rejected when directly copied in the cider-repl, even after including namespace clojure.test. Plus when evaluating one of the (is ...) blocks, the answer is '=> nil' whereas it should be '=> true' or '=> false'

Comment: Please also see the part of the template project README that talks about the `test-refresh` usage. IMHO it is even better & faster than using the REPL.

Comment: Hi, @Francois sorry if I didn't get it but I'd like to understand the problem better. My first impression is that this assert function is not in the right place, but I could be wrong haha. 

I tried to do it in IntelliJ and it didn't work too.

Do you try to do something like it? 



```
(defn my-function2
  {:test #(do
            (assert (= 4 (my-function2 2 2)))
            (assert (= 7 (my-function2 3 4))))}
  ([x y] (+ x y)))
```

Comment: 'is' is an helper macro equivalent to 'assert' here. The assert in `my-function` is meant to provoke an error and see how the unit-tests would catch it. My emacs environment is messed-up anyway since half of cider shortcuts do not work.